# MVC - should the model be a different class from the controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, xcode4

I’m learning cocoa (not ios) and I want to understand and implement MVC in all the code I create. I have learnt and understand the logic for this design and I am trying to use it in my apps  (very small apps from lessons and tutorials etc..).

Most tutorials show examples of MVC in just 2 files. The Model and the appController together in one class/file (a sub class of NSObject) and then the view obviously in its own file (NSView).
But when I think of MVC, I always think of 3 classes in 3 files:

Class/file 1. The Model  e.g.  names, people, ages , arrays etc..
Class/file 2. The appController  - the brain e.g. give person a name and age etc…
Class/file 3. The view e.g. show the person in a window.

So should the model always be in a separate file from the controller?

The other question is regarding communication – On the above example, how would the Model and appController share data ? Would the Model be a subclass of the appController (appController a subClass of NSObject) so both can share ivars ??

Thanks for reading this and I hope you can clear my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that the Model is somewhat more abstract than the View and ViewController.

The Model may be a class but if it is a straightforward model, (say just a single value that the ViewController can get from some other ViewController) it may just be in the ViewController.

The key point is that the View never owns its own data, it just displays it. 
Lecture 1 in CS193P has a lot of good illustrations and has a download of the lecture as a pdf [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2011-fall)

Also, although a view should never own its own data, where that data is entirely derived from what is in the view (a box in the view for instance whose size is derived from the amount of data received), that box size could be worked out by the View when it is drawing itself.

Also, there is an example of the Calculator that this lecture refers to [here](https://github.com/i4-apps/Top-Places).
I learned a great deal about the concepts in these places. I just struggle with syntax now.

Answer (score 2):

You are right about the models, these could be abstract data types like people,news, etc. You can say that your business objects form your model. Views are how do you represent your data, e.g I have to show a news item in tableViewCell, i ll create a view containing a headlines, date and time for that news. But this view wont communicate directly with the model to get the data.
Here your controller, that you are calling brain, comes in. your controller knows that this view is to be displayed. and your controller has the model object news object in this case. 
So it will give the give data from model object to the view to populate the view. So here comes the answer to your second question, you dont need to have model as subclass of the app Controller. But your controller has the object of your model. this object is in its final stage to used for. 
So key points are:
models are separate from the controllers, and view both.
Views and model do not communicate directly.
controllers work as a source of communication between views and model.
model are not subclasses of appcontroller. 
your controller can have to model object to use it.

Hope it would have clarified your confusion.

Comment: @Ehsan- Thanks Ehsan – I really appreciate your time on this. So a couple of questions:

I’m still a little bit confused regarding communication between the controller and the model.  

When you say, the controller has an object of the model in it final stage. Are you saying that I should actually create an instance/object of the model in my appController ? 

If yes, I thought if I make an object from the model class in my appController I can get the properties of my model (arrays etc) but not the actual values (string names etc) !!

Damm … as I’m writing this I’m realizing how confused I am !

Comment: Confusion sorted! I forgot that if I initilize my values with the init method in the implementation file of the model, all the values can be imported when I import the model into the appController.